# How to prevent "The connection was reset" error?

Tags: ruby, sockets, networking, tcpserver

I have a very basic TCP server implemented in Ruby.  In general it does what it's supposed to, but every once in a while I get *"The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading"* error.  I have a feeling that it has something to do with `close` terminating the connection too soon.  If so, how do I wait for all the data to be sent?  Or is it something else?

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new('', 80)
loop do
    session = server.accept
    begin
        session.print Time.now
    ensure
        session.close
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because the browser is expecting an HTTP response with headers &c.  Curiously, you can make the "reset" error happen every time if you put before the "ensure" a sleep of, say, one second.

How to fix it depends upon what you are after.  If this is not to be an HTTP server, then don't use the browser to test it.  Instead, use telnet or write a little program.  If it is to be an HTTP server, then take a look at [webrick](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/index.html), which is built into Ruby MRI >= 1.8.  Here's how:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

require 'webrick'

# This class handles time requests

class TimeServer < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet

  def do_GET(request, response)
    response.status = 200
    response['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    response.body = Time.now.to_s
  end

end

# Create the server.  There are many other options, if you need them.
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port=>8080)

# Whenever a request comes in for the root page, use TimeServer to handle it
server.mount('/', TimeServer)

# Finally, start the server.  Does not normally return.
server.start
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm already playing with it and it doesn't generate that error.  I'm still curious though if the original example could be fixed.  In C# it's possible to call `Close` on a socket with a timeout and it fixes the same problem in the .NET world.

Comment: @detunized, I'm embarrassed to say I don't know.  Hopefully someone will come along and help us both out.

Comment: Though this doesn't answer my original question, thanks for sharing the thoughts.  I ended up doing this anyway.  Still would be interested to know why that happens and how to prevent it.

Comment: @detunized: Thank you for the checkmark on this "not really the answer to your question" answer.  Hopefully someone comes along who truly deserves the checkmark, because I'd like to know the answer to your question as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in this area, but here is what I believe is happening....

The browser sends a GET request with the header field "Connection:  keep-alive".  So the browser is expecting to keep the connection alive at least until it receives a complete chunk of the response.  Under this protocol, the server response must include a header specifying the length of the response, so that the browser knows when it has received the complete response.  After this point, the connection can be closed without the browser caring.

The original example closes the connection too quickly, before the browser can validate that a complete response was received.  Curiously, if I run that example and refresh my browser several times, it will load about every 1 in 10 tries.  Maybe this erratic behavior is due to the browser occasionally executing fast enough to beat my server closing the connection.

Below is a code example that executes consistently in my browser:

```
require 'socket'

response = %{HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 12

Hello World!
}

server = TCPServer.open(80)

loop do
  client = server.accept
  client.puts response
  sleep 1
  client.close
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, should note that including `Connection: close` in the response header doesn't seem to help me at all with this connection reset error in my browser (FFv3.6).  I have to include both the `content-length` header field, and include the `sleep` method to put some delay in the connection closing in order to get a consistent response in my browser.